# Force destroying servlet session

Tags: session, servlets, sessionid

I have some question about servlet session.I have about create web apps with jsf, with configuration in web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

thats mean session never timeout

I also save the created session id from everyone has logged to database.

my question is  how about force destroying all active session with session id 
that i have saved in database.

the situation i want to have a admin page, 
i can list all active session id
and i can destroy it.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `HttpSessionListener` and on each `sessionCreated(..)` to fill a static `List` with the active sessions.

Then, from the admin interface you can iterate these sessions and call `.invalidate()` on each.